# Is it possible to hire graduate students as freelancers?

Tags: job, job-search, independent-researcher, research-assistantship

I am currently working in the engineering industry. I am developing software in this field in my free time. I got stuck in some algorithm, and I'm looking for help from academia (either professors or students).

Is it possible to hire professors or students from universities to develop an algorithm for me?
Do universities have some kind of forum to invite projects for its researchers?

(I also considered the option to hire from popular websites for freelancers; however, it is difficult to find many people who freelance in engineering. My budget is  between 500 USD to 1000 USD for around 10 hours of work.)

Comment: Are you sure 10 hours total is enough?

Comment: 10 hours to *develop an algorithm* is very optimistic.

Comment: I know for sure that algorithms for my  problem already exist. Hopefully some people in academia already have them handy.  My expectation is that they just share the algorithm or   teach me how to do .

Comment: If the algorithm already exists, you should be able to find it yourself in some publications. If you need somebody to teach it to you, you may need to have prior knowledge, it won't be a 10 hour job.

Comment: yeah, they are human, you can hire them to do stuff, just find the right person and the right price. That being said, good luck finding that person and a way to search for that person. Profs at my university are willing to help the public and use students to help out, however, the projects they tackle are to help better the community, so that there is different from what you want. Best of luck.

Comment: If your problem really just is "I want to do X and Y under constraints Z, what is the state of the art way to do this?" it is also possible to just ask on the relevant SE (not this one). Of course you need to do some background research first (namely to figure out X, Y and Z), but the same is also true if you would hire somebody - even in that case you would need to be prepared to tell the person pretty explicitly what you need for it to be a 10-hour job.

Comment: Have you tried asking on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)?

Answer (score 3):

While people are, perhaps rightly, poking at your estimate of how long this will take and your budget, yes, its entirely possible to hire graduate students as freelancers. I worked on several projects during my graduate career as a consultant or freelancer. Generally speaking, there aren't great university resources for it, though you might contact a professor who works in the area to see if he or she have any students who might be interested in a consulting gig.

Comment: May I ask, _several projects during my graduate career as a consultant or freelancer._ were with industry companies/academic institutes or individuals?